# Distributing Hotel WLAN connection to multiple WLAN clients

Tags: wireless-networking

I hope I'm missing something but I've searched everywhere but couldn't find a solution - either homegrown or commercial. I travel a lot and this spent a lot of time in Hotel Rooms. Many of the Hotels only allow one MAC address per account. So I'm looking for something providing the following:

- Connects to the Hotel's WLAN as CLient
- Shares this connection with multiple WLAN on private Subnet like an ordinary router (NAT)

Kinda like a WLAN to WLAN Distribution to NAT clients.

Answer (score 2):

Geekbeat had a review of a product that looks to do what you are asking. The [D-Link SharePort](http://geekbeat.tv/d-link-shareport-go-review/) shares one connection with multiple devices.

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You don't mentioned which OS you are using but i give solution for Windows and MacOS:

The general solution is you have to make your laptop as **HOTSPOT**.

In MacOS try this :

> System Preferences-> Sharing -> internet Sharing-> Select the USB Dongle as the source,
>   and Airport Wireless as the Share via.

In Windows:

You can't do it if your windows **earlier than Windows7** because they don't included the Virtual WiFi components. But in **later version of windows 7(Include win7)** you have to download softwares like [Virtual router](http://virtualrouter.codeplex.com/) to make your system as HOTSPOT.

Comment: Excellent, didnt know this.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Connectify Hotspot](http://connectify.me), and even the free version works great.

> Connectify Hotspot is an easy to use software router for Windows that
>   utilizes your PC’s built in Wi-Fi card to wirelessly share any
>   available Internet connection with friends, co-workers, and mobile
>   devices.